# How do I mock authenticate with Nuxt and Cypress?

Tags: testing, nuxt.js, cypress

## How do I mock authenticate with Nuxt and Cypress?

I have a FastAPI backend that issues a JWT to a frontend NuxtJS application. I want to test the frontend using Cypress. I am battling to mock authenticate.

Here is a simple Cypress test:

```js
// cypress/e2e/user_authentication_test.cy.js

describe("A User logging in", () => {
  it.only("can login by supplying the correct credentials", () => {
    cy.mockLogin().then(() => {
      cy.visit(`${Cypress.env("BASE_URL")}/dashboard`)
        .window()
        .its("$nuxt.$auth")
        .its("loggedIn")
        .should("equal", true);
    });
  });
});
```

The test above fails at the `should` assertion, and the user is not redirected.

The `mockLogin` command is defined as:

```js
// cypress/support/commands.js

Cypress.Commands.add(
  'mockLogin',
  (username = 'someone', password = 'my_secret_password_123') => {
    cy.intercept('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/token', {
      fixture: 'auth/valid_auth_token.json',
    }).as('token_mock')

    cy.visit(`${Cypress.env('BASE_URL')}/login`)

    cy.get('#login-username').type(username)
    cy.get('#login-password').type(`${password}{enter}`)

    cy.wait('@token_mock')
  }
)
```

Where `valid_auth_token.json` contains a JWT.

The actual login is done as follows:

```js
<!-- components/auth/LoginForm.vue -->

<template>
  <!-- Login form goes here -->
</template>

<script>
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode' // eslint-disable-line camelcase

export default {
  name: 'LoginForm',
  data() {
    return {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async login() {
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('username', this.username)
      formData.append('password', this.password)

      try {
        await this.$auth
          .loginWith('cookie', {
            data: formData,
          })
          .then((res) => {
            const decode = jwt_decode(res.data.access_token) // eslint-disable-line camelcase
            this.$auth.setUser(decode)
            this.$router.push('/')
          })
      } catch (error) {
        // error handling
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```